# vscode - Could not fetch model of type 'GradleProject' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip'

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I was trying to build a gradle project but it returned with an error:

```
CONFIGURE FAILED in 14s
[error] [gradle-server] Could not fetch model of type 'GradleProject' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip'.
[error] Error getting build for c:\Users\meee\OneDrive\Desktop\fabric-example-mod: Could not fetch model of type 'GradleProject' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip'.
[info] Found 0 tasks
```

I'm using vscode for this

I saw some questions similar to this but they were about android studio, and I couldn't find anything else about it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue has been resolved on github: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2177, apparently it's because of onedrive

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to [Gradle project fails to build while fetching non-existing snapshot distro](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1285).

Please manually install the latest CI build (0.83.0) from [here](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/jdt.ls/staging/). Delete `.project`, `.settings/`, `~/.toolings/` and clean the workspace directory. See if the error goes away.

Comment: just wondering which one to use, there are several builds with '0.83.0' on it

Comment: @somebodysomeone. There's 1.0 released. try the latest one.

Comment: It still throws the same exception :/

Comment: @somebodysomeone. Which gradle you're using? Does the error occur even when you create the simplest gradle project?